# Writing r shiny leaflet |popup|

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet

Any solution/help about writing `r shiny leaflet` |popup|.
Thinks

I am trying to put some informations into my R shiny leaflet tool, and I got a problem to write something like that:

```
popup = paste(data$url,data$nom)
```

The problem is that in the code the data$url is a website, and I want to render it like a link?

and when I try making with the ~symbol I got error messages ...

```
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles(
    urlTemplate = "//{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/jcheng.map-5ebohr46/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
    attribution = 'Maps by <a href="http://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>'
  ) %>%
  setView(lng =  LONG, lat = LAT , zoom = ZOOM)%>%
  addMarkers(data,lng=data$Longitude,lat=data$Latitude,
  popup = paste(data$url,data$nom)
 ) %>%
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use html tags for that. Just change your popup to the following:

```
 popup = paste("<a href=",data$url,">",data$url,"</a>",data$nom)
```